# How do i refer to rows/ columns in data frames that are within a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm looking to work with the data frames I have within a list. I'm getting 'incorrect number of subscripts' and similar errors, despite my current best efforts. Here's my code:

```
folder = 'C:/Path to csv files-071813/'
symbs = c('SPX', 'XLF', 'XLY', 'XLV', 'XLI', 'IYZ', 'XLP', 'XLE', 'XLK', 'XLB', 'XLU', 'SHV')
importData = vector('list', length(symbs))
names(importData) = symbs

for (sIdx in 1:length(symbs)){
    #Import the data for each symbol into the list.
    importData[sIdx] = read.csv(paste(folder, symbs[sIdx], '.csv', sep = ''), header = TRUE)

}
```

Each csv file is thousands of rows, and 7 columns.
I'm assuming what I have above is returning a data frame from each csv file, into my list.
I'd like to enter:

`importData[[1]][, 1]`

to work with the first column of the first data frame in my list. Am I close? I can't find resolution despite all my searching. Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Try `importData[[sIdx]] = read.csv(...`, that should fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apply` family of functions are going to be your friend here, specifically `lapply`, a function which, given a list and a function, applies the function to every element of that list and returns the results as elements of a new list.

```
folder = 'C:/Path to csv files-071813/'
symbs = c('SPX', 'XLF', 'XLY', 'XLV', 'XLI', 'IYZ', 'XLP', 'XLE', 'XLK', 'XLB', 'XLU', 'SHV')
filenames = paste0(folder,symbs,'.csv')
listOfDataframes=lapply(filenames,read.table,header=T)
```

Now if you want the second column from all the dataframes you could do something like

```
listOfFirstCols=lapply(listOfDataframes,"[",,2)
```

Or more explicitly

```
listOfFirstCols=lapply(listOfDataframes,function(x)x[,1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I've read just enough about R to know that I need to get away from loops. I'll be working with yours over the weekend.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh, who says you need to get away from loops? R generally works fine with well-written loops....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are close. You need

```
importData[[sIdx]] <- read.csv(....)
```

(i.e. `[[`) as you want to assign a data frame *inside* the `sIdx`th component. Single brackets `[` would require a list to be assigned.

`importData[[1]]` returns the object inside `importData[1]`. This is a subtle difference, with the latter returning a list containing the first component, whereas the former returns the object inside that list.

As `importData[[sIdx]]` is a data frame, you can index it as you would any other data frame. It might help to think of `importData[[sIdx]]` as data frame `df` and then add on to that what you would normally use to index the first column, i.e. `df[, 1]` (or alternatively `df[[1]]`), then substitute back in the real object instead of `df`

```
                df[, 1]
importData[[sIdx]][, 1] ## substitute back in the real object for `df`
```

If you want to extract each first column in turn, then

```
lapply(importData, `[`, , 1) ## matches df[, 1]
```

or

```
lapply(importData, `[[`, 1)  ## matches df[[1]]
```

will return them as a list, with versions using `sapply()` instead of `lapply()` simplifying the result to an array where possible.

Note that in the first example

```
lapply(importData, `[`, , 1)
```

the empty argument (`, , 1`) is important as it refers to the empty argument in `df[ , 1]`, i.e. the bit before the comma. Hence the second option, using `[[` in the `lapply()` call may be less error-prone and why I mentioned it earlier.

Comment: I wish I could check 2 as answered. I took the one with the lesson in functional programming. Thank you for the direct answer.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh You do realise that both Answers are applying a function, but the explicit (I would say this is exactly opposite of explicit) version in nwknoblauch's Answer uses an Anonymous function, which is not a elegant or efficient (R has to create the function where as `'[['()` already exists *as a function* -though the inefficiency will be small). When we use `'[['`, that actually corresponds to the function `'[['()` just like `+` is really the function `'+'()` etc.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh I don't say that to prompt a change of heart on the Accept, just that your reasoning seemed to suggest you hadn't quite fully understood what the two Answers are doing.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I used the anonymous function to demonstrate that the second argument to lapply is a function.  If you aren't used to using higher order functions (functions which take functions as parameters), the function `'['` looks a bit more like a character argument than a function.

Comment: @nwknoblauch That wasn't a criticism of your Answer (a quibble about explicit - but that depends on your viewpoint). It was more a comment on the OP's suggesting yours was in some way different because you used `function`. I was simply trying to point out that the two are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
>  myfunc<-function(a,b){ ###a is numeric (vector of) symbol indices to
> include,b is (vector of) column indices to include
>        if (length(a)>0){
>           importalldata<-read.csv(paste(folder, symbs[a[1]], '.csv', sep = ''), header = TRUE)[b]
>        if (length(a)>1){
>           for(i in 2:length(d)){
>              importalldata<-rbind(importalldata,read.csv(paste(folder, symbs[a[i]], '.csv', sep = ''), header = TRUE)[b])
>           }
>        }else{print('Must select at least one symbol')}
>     return(importalldata)
>     }
```

to load your data for one symbol, do:

```
importalldata<-myfunc(1,1)
```

for multiple symbols:

```
importalldata<-myfunc(c(1,3,4),1)
```

for multiple columns:

```
importalldata<-myfunc(c(1,3,4),1:3)
```

I think that is what you want? Or are you trying to get all column 1's for each file into 1 dataframe? If you include reproducible data, you will get a better answer.

That said, thousands of rows isn't much and you will would likely be better off combining ('stacking') your data into 1 csv with your symbls as a factors, and then using subset/data.table package to select the data you want. Check out

```
?stack
```